# GAS - Concatenate Unique List + Sumifs

Tags: google-sheets

I am really struggling with this to come up with an easy way to do this in Google Sheets.

1. I need a unique list with filter. 
   Fairly straight forward:
   `Unique(Filter(UniqueRange,FilterRange,Criteria)`
2. I need to sumifs that list.  If i do it one row at a time, its fairly straight forward pointing one of my criterias to the result of #1 and copy it downward:
   `sumifs(SumRange, Criteria1Range, Criteria1, Criteria2Range, Criteria2))`

What i am struggling with is, i do not know how far that unique list will go.  So i do not know how far down to copy #2's formula.  Its no big deal if i had unlimited rows but i need to output the results of the above to all show up in a single cell with a character between the results because i am trying to make all this fit in a "calendar" for a dashboard.  Can this even be done?

Sample Data:

```
 Apple  | 2
 Orange | 3
 Red    | 1
 Green  | 4
 Orange | 5
 Red    | 2
```

Simple result i have now by letting the uniques list grow as needed on the left column and copying formula #2 downward on the right hand column:

```
 Apple  | 2
 Orange | 8
 Red    | 3
 Green  | 4
```

My question again is, is there a way to have the below result all show up in a single cell and toss in a hyphen between the results?

```
 Apple  - 2
 Orange - 8
 Red    - 3
 Green  - 4
```

EDIT:
Thank you all for the help.

@theMayer
You pointed me in the right direction and ended up solving my issue.  Thank you!

@I'-'I
Helper columns will just not work for my needs.

What i ended up doing is modifying the solution a little.  I modified it to have a " _ " between the data because the data had hyphens in it and it was confusing.  As for the number formatting, ill just leave it out for now.  Here is my final code along with an additional date filter in the select query:

`ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(CONCATENATE(QUERY({CHAR(10)&$G$3:$G,$F$3:$F,$A$3:$A},"select Col1,' _ ',sum(Col2) where Col3 = date '" & text(C3,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(CONCATENATE(QUERY({CHAR(10)&A1:A6,--("-"&B1:B6)},"select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"))))
```

Comment: If this is intended to answer the question, it should be formatted to explain how to address one or more of the issues in the original question, as opposed to simply being a snippet of code.

Comment: Actually, this solved my problem!  I have two questions on it though.  
1.  How do i format the hyphen between the data so it has a space before and after it.  Modifying the formula does not seem to help.  "Value - Value"

2.  How can i add a format to the resulted sum like this:  #,### ?